# Postgres hashing user defined types

Tags: sql, postgresql, hash, typing

**Note:** m4 is being used so "_" prefixed strings are expanded (m4 is a macro pre-processor similar to the c preprocessor).

My Type:

```
CREATE TYPE UrlPair AS (                                                      
    HostName        varchar( _LIMIT_HOSTNAME ),                               
    ScriptName      varchar( _LIMIT_SCRIPTNAME )                              
);
```

Used in

```
CREATE TABLE SymbolTable_UrlPair (
    Symbol          _BIG_SYMBOL_SERIAL_TYPE     PRIMARY KEY,
    UrlPair         UrlPair                     
);
```

With index

```
CREATE INDEX SymbolTable_UrlPair_UrlPair 
    ON SymbolTable_UrlPair USING hash (UrlPair);
```

Gives:

```
psql:script:32: ERROR:  data type urlpair has no default operator class 
for access method "hash"

HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default 
operator class for the data type.
```

**Question**

Ideally I would like the engine to concatinate the strings and use that for a hash. However, I am not fussy. Could someone show me the syntax for declaring this "Operator Class" for the access method hash.

I would have expected some default hashing behaviour for user defined types. I would really preffer to keep the type -- i.e., I don't want to expand it, as I will probably define a few more elaborate UDT's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashing and a hash index are two different things. Hash indexes don't support a multi column index, that might be the problem, your type UrlPair is multi value.

What's wrong with a Btree-index? What problem do have to solve?

Comment: Symbolizing URLs in a very large database. A Linear Hashed index is preferable to a B-tree for strings AFAIK http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-createindex.html. This page states that a 'func_name' can be specified which is used to return a value that can be indexed. I am usuming this will allow the  UDT to return a single entity that can be hashed (in my case a concatination of the URL).

Comment: Hmm switching to B-tree worked. I guess I will stick to a B-tree as I will probably use a range based scan on hostname. However I would still be interested in the syntax for the access method.

Comment: @hassan: you're not actually using PostgreSQL 7.3, I hope? If so, your first thing to do is to get a supported, non-ancient release. And note that in most cases, btree indexes perform as good as or better than hash in PostgreSQL today.

Comment: Thanks, no I am working with 8.4. It is good to hear that about B-Trees